# Unit testing - how to test a method that takes in a lambda function?

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, junit, kotlin

can someone help me to figure out how i can unit tests the below code effectively. its kotlin but can be anything:

```
 myMainObject.doSomethingSpecial({ differentObject ->
                differentObject.doFirst()
                differentObject.doSecond()
                differentObject.doThird()
            })
```

i would like to test that doSomethingSpecial actually works.

i thought about trying to mock the lambda:

```
val function1: () -> Int = mock()
    whenever(function1.invoke())
        .thenReturn(1)
```

but this is not what i really want. i want to test that all the methods in the lamda get called so i want to test that **doFirst,doSecond,doThird**, etc are all called i think is how best to unit test this.  do i have use argument capture for this, how ? To be clear, my question is how to unit test the method doSomethingSpecial ?

Comment: So, you would test the lambda rather than the `doSomethingSpecial`, isn't it? May be you can pass to the `doSomethingSpecial` method a _fake_ lambda and test that it is called when you call `doSomethingSpecial`...

Comment: interesting idea. so if i want to test the lamaba afterwards how would i test that it called all those methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to split the problem into two simpler problems:

1. you can test the `doSomethingSpecial` (which I suppose calls the function it receives a parameter) passing a *fake* function as parameter and testing it was called
2. you can test the lambda giving it a name and testing it as function: you call it passing a *mock* for `differentObject` and test *mock*'s method were called

So, in pseudo-code:

```
val myFunction = { differentObject ->
        differentObject.doFirst()
        differentObject.doSecond()
        differentObject.doThird()
        differentObject.doFourth()
        differentObject.doFifth()
}
myMainObject.doSomethingSpecial(myFunction)

// Invoke doSomethingSpecial with fake parameter
val fakeFunction = ...
myMainObject.doSomethingSpecial(fakeFunction)
// Assert fakeFunction was called

// Invoke myFunction with mock parameter
val mockObject = ...
myFunction(mockObject)
// Assert mockObject.doNth was called
```

I hope this approach can help you toward a real solution!